# Why I am not able to find spark.implicits._ in scala REPL / Shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am on MacOS.

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
              ^
       error: not found: value spark
```

WHY?

```
scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 13.0.2).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How to solve this problem?

If I try spark-shell

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
```

Works fine.

Comment: run in the spark-shell?

Comment: @thebluephantom I made an edit,pls take a look.

Comment: OK, cool. that warning is no issue.

Comment: @Djikii, you got your answer? If no elaborate more on your question. Which means in the first command are you trying directly from scala repl? or you are trying with IDE where you scala repl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importation in Scala is a mechanism that enables more direct reference of different entities such as packages, classes, objects, instances, fields and methods.

`import spark.implicits._` are provided by the Spark includes and various libraries for the Spark api, program, run-time, classes whatever you want to call it.

scala inside Spark is simply the interface for using spark-shell, it can be java, scala or python known as pyspark then.

scala on its own has no notion of where to get that specific import from, i.e. not in the scala supplied binaries, apis, methods, classes, libraries.

If using tools like SBT, IntelliJ then you provide *dependencies* that allow that import to be found, resolved.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running the scala repl you have to add the jar to the classpath by executing:

```
:require <path-to-jar>
```

Comment: In the Spark shell the Spark dependencies are added automatically. There is no need to add them explicitly. Don't let the "spark>" prompt in the question confuse you. The Spark shell is a Scala repl under the hood, but with Spark specific additional configurations

Comment: Thanks for the clarification